# variable is not updated when row selected in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm trying to modify a variable with the number of the row selected in a UITableView, so that I can access that variable from another UIViewController but when I'm setting the value of the variable with the row number in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` it appears that the variable is not changed.

I've a View Controller with an UITableView, what I'd like is to select a row, then, when I click on a button a Popoverview appear where I can parameterize things linked to the row I selected.

Here is what I've done :

```
import UIKit

class Settings: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, 
UITableViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var RowSelected = Int()

    let animals = ["Tap", "Double Tap", "Long press", "Swipe up", "Swipe down", "Swipe left", "Swipe right", "Zoom", "Unzoom"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell"/*Identifier*/, for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = animals[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return animals.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    RowSelected = indexPath.row
    print(RowSelected)
}

}
```

It print the row perfectly here, but when I access it from the other ViewController it's always equal to 0.

```
import UIKit

class GestureConfiguration: UIViewController, 
UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var actionSelected: UILabel!

let reuseIdentifier = "cell" // also enter this string as the cell identifier in the storyboard
var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var index : Int = 1

var scVC = Settings()

let gestes = ["Tap", "Double Tap", "Long press", "Swipe up", "Swipe down", "Swipe left", "Swipe right", "Zoom", "Unzoom"]

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 9
}

// tell the collection view how many cells to make
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.items.count
}

// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.37, blue:0.58, alpha:0.7)
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1

    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item + 1) section \(indexPath.section + 1)")
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.28, blue:0.45, alpha:1.0)
    ///////// HERE \\\\\\\\\\
    actionSelected.text = String(scVC.RowSelected)
    print(scVC.RowSelected)
    // Always print 0, same for the label.
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    print("You unselected cell #\(indexPath.item + 1) section \(indexPath.section + 1)")
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.37, blue:0.58, alpha:0.7)
}
```

What am I missing?  When I hardcode a value to RowSelected (like 99), I'm able to see 99 in my second ViewController.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT for Akhilrajtr :

```
class Settings: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var RowSelected = Int()

let animals = ["Tap", "Double Tap", "Long press", "Swipe up", "Swipe down", "Swipe left", "Swipe right", "Zoom", "Unzoom"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell"/*Identifier*/, for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = animals[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return animals.count
}

//Not overriding any function, 
Override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "toPopover") {
        var secondViewContr =  segue.destination as! GestureConfiguration
        secondViewContr.scVC = self
    }
}
}
```

And:

```
class GestureConfiguration: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var actionSelected: UILabel!

var scVC = Settings()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item + 1) section \(indexPath.section + 1)")
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.28, blue:0.45, alpha:1.0)

    actionSelected.text = String(scVC.RowSelected)
    print(scVC.RowSelected)
}
```

Comment: in the second view controller you are creating `var scVC = Settings()` new instance. so the `RowSelected` will be default value. How you are showing second viewcontroller?

Comment: Hum, I understand where is my mistake now, thanks. But, how can I correct that? any help?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr with a segue (with an identifier)

Comment: then you can use `prepareForSegue` to pass value to second view controller. i've added an answer try that.

Comment: just declare var RowSelected = Int() global

Comment: For better conceptual idea, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `GestureConfiguration` create one variable of `Settings class` and then access it in your `tableViewDelegate` function.

In `Settings` class override function `prepareforsegue` as

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if let gestuedistination = segue.destination as? GestureConfiguration {
            gestuedistination.settings = self
        }
}
```

In `GestureConfiguration` class declare

```
@IBOutlet weak var actionSelected: UILabel!
var settings:Settings?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item + 1) section \(indexPath.section + 1)")
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.28, blue:0.45, alpha:1.0)
        actionSelected.text = String(settings!.RowSelected)
        print(settings!.RowSelected)
}
```

Comment: I've an "instance member "settings" cannot be used on type "GestureConfiguration" error" on GestureConfiguration.settings = self;

Comment: @Hawkydoky check updated answer i just change gestuedistination.settings = self

Comment: Please debug the value of settings!.RowSelected and check it is 0 or not,
if it is correct than you have change  weak var actionSelected: UILabel! to 
var actionSelected: UILabel! and check the connection is correctly connected to storyboard or not.

Comment: sorry, I miss placed something in my code, it's ok, it's working. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using segue to show the second view controller, then in Settings view controller implement the below method

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "your segue id") {
        var secondViewController =  segue.destinationViewController as! GestureConfiguration
        secondViewController.scVC = self
    }
}
```

if you just need the selected row identifier, then create a `var` in `GestureConfiguration` and set it from `prepareForSegue`

Comment: Yes I just need the selected row identifier. I'm new to swift, So I don't really understand what you mean by "set it from prepareForSegue" something like 'var varName = prepareForSegue' ? Looks weird to me.

Comment: you can implement `prepareForSegue` as above in Settings view controller. and instead of `"your segue id"` use the correct segue identifier from storyboard. if not set any identifier, you can set one by selecting that segue. then the above code will do the requirement.

Comment: Same as bellow I've an instance member "scVC" cannot be used on type "GestureConfiguration". Plus It doesn't override a function.

Comment: the prepare for segue method signature was wrong, i've updated that in answer. `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` try with this

Comment: @Nikhlesh Bagdiya answered worked. But thanks for your help and time, you pointed thing I wasn't able to see :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the issue is because you are instantiating a new view controller in `var scVC = Settings()`. Instead, whenever you create this `GestureConfiguration` view controller, you should pass the reference to the proper `Settings` view controller so that `RowSelected` is what you want.

(Although it would be better just to pass `RowSelected` itself instead of the entire `Settings` view controller unless you need the view controller for other things)

Answer (score 0):

Make globlal object of setting var globalSetVC = Settings() and in setting view controller save rowSelect like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) {globalSetVC.RowSelected = indexPath.row print(globalSetVC.RowSelected)}
```

use it where ever require as globalSetVC.RowSelected